# Golang: Как остановить загрузку большого файла

Tags: golang

Есть функция DownloadByLink() которая выполняется условно 10 мин(загрузка файла). Как прервать выполнение функции DownloadByLink по требованию, из другой функции?

Функция которую нужно прорвать

```
// DownloadByLink ...
func (r bigfileRepository) DownloadByLink(bf *model.Bigfile) error {

    resp, err := http.Get(bf.Link)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        zap.L().Error(fmt.Sprintf("error download file by link. code: %d status: %s", resp.StatusCode, resp.Status), zap.Error(err))
        return err
    }

    zap.L().Info("file download beginning",
        zap.String("name", bf.Name),
        zap.String("uuid", fmt.Sprintln(bf.Uuid)),
        zap.String("link", bf.Link),
    )

    defer resp.Body.Close()

    bytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    bf.FileBytes = bytes
    bf.Size = len(bytes)

    zap.L().Info("file download complete",
        zap.String("name", bf.Name),
        zap.String("uuid", fmt.Sprintln(bf.Uuid)),
        zap.String("size", fmt.Sprintln(bf.Size)),
        zap.String("link", bf.Link),
    )

    return nil
}
```

Comment: используйте NewRequestWithContext или http.Client timeout

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно прикрепить к запросу контекст с заданным дедлайном. Http клиент в go умеет отслеживать истечение дедлайна и завершать запрос.

Вот пример:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "errors"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, 5*time.Second)

    // Request with 20 seconds delay
    req, err := http.NewRequestWithContext(ctx, "GET", "http://httpbin.org/delay/20", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("%v", err)
        return
    }

    defer cancel() // Cleanup resources

    client := http.DefaultClient
    resp, err := client.Do(req) // Execute the request

    if err != nil {
        if errors.Is(errors.Unwrap(err), context.DeadlineExceeded) {
            log.Fatal("Request failed: Context deadline exceeded")
        } else {
            log.Fatalf("Request failed: %#v", err)
        }
    } else {
        log.Printf("Request executed: %v\n", resp.StatusCode)
    }

}
```